# Writing to Excel data validation from Python in a .xslm file

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe, openpyxl

I have an Excel file that has to be in a macro-enabled workbook (.xlsm) that has a named range called `names_to_match`. The output of a different function will take those company names, match them against a database and return the top 5 matches along with each one's match score, match name, and match index.

The goal would be go name by name in the .xlsm file, and if the highest match score is 100 (Assume the name is column A). column B would then be the highest match name and column C would be the match score of 100.

The tricky part is if the match score is less than 100, column b should be a data validation list of all the match names plus one entry called "create new entry".

The problem I'm having is after struggling to get this to work using  `openpyxl` for days, I was finally able to use `xlsxwriter` to get it to work in my sample file. However, as soon as I tried to use it on my actual file, it didn't work b/c xlsxwriter doesn't support .xlsm extensions.

Here is the code I've attempted in `openpyxl`. Is it possible to do this in `openpyxl`? If not, is there another workaround for the .xlsm file extension?

```
from sqlupdate import data_frame_from_xlsx_range
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import Workbook

def read_data():
    # Read in the data from the two Excel files
    df_names = data_frame_from_xlsx_range('excel_write_test.xlsm', 'names_to_match')
    df_db_pull = pd.read_excel('test_with_db_pull.xlsx')
    return df_names, df_db_pull


def process_row(row, df_db_pull):
    # Find the corresponding name in the test_with_db_pull dataframe
    match_row = df_db_pull.loc[df_db_pull['original_name'] == row['Tracker_Name'], :]

    # Check if the score is 100
    if match_row['score_0'].values[0] == 100:
        # Set the value in column B to the match index
        row['Possible Matches'] = [match_row['match_name_0'].values[0]]
        # Set the value in column C to the score
        row['Match Score'] = match_row['score_0'].values[0]

    else:
        # Get the unique values in the match name columns
        match_names = set(
            match_row[['match_name_0', 'match_name_1', 'match_name_2',
 'match_name_3', 'match_name_4']].values.ravel())
            # Remove any NaN values
            match_names.discard(float('nan'))
            match_names = {x for x in match_names if pd.notnull(x)}
            match_names = list(match_names) + ['Create New Database Entry']
    
            # Set the value in column B to a list of the match names
            row['Possible Matches'] = match_names
            # Set the value in column C to the highest score
            row['Match Score'] = match_row[['score_0', 'score_1', 'score_2', 'score_3', 'score_4']].max().values[0]
    
        return row
    
    
    def create_dropdowns(df):
        # Get the workbook and the worksheet
        workbook = Workbook()
        worksheet = workbook.active
    
        # Write the dataframe to the worksheet
        df.to_excel(worksheet, index=False)
    
        # Loop over the dataframe's 'Possible Matches' column and create a data validation for each row
        for idx, item in enumerate(df['Possible Matches'], start=2):
            # Prepare a list of options
            options = item
    
            # Create a data validation object with the list of options
            dv = {'validate': 'list',
                  'source': options}
    
            # Add data validation to the corresponding cell in the worksheet
            worksheet.cell(row=idx, column=1).data_validation = dv
    
        # Save the workbook
        workbook.save_as('excel_write_test.xlsm')
    
    
    def main():
        df_names, df_db_pull = read_data()
    
        # Process each row
        df_names['Possible Matches'] = None
        df_names['Match Score'] = None
        df_names = df_names.apply(process_row, df_db_pull=df_db_pull, axis=1)

    # Create the dropdowns in the Excel file
    create_dropdowns(df_names)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Why are you using an exteral library to look for the defined names? Seems to me like it would be easier to do most of the work directly in openpyxl.

Comment: yea probably - im not a native programmer. I couldn't get that to work initially and ended up finding that solution somewhere on here.